# whats programming language is this syntax?

Tags: php

while I was searching through some file in a php library, i found some documents like this

```
a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:3:"cnt";s:1:"1";}}
```

This is definitely not JSON. Does any one know what is this?  or is it a custom syntax for the  guy who wrote the library ?

Comment: search for php serialize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [`serialized`](https://www.php.net/serialize) data and not any programming language syntax.

For your understanding...

```
<?php
$arr = ['a'=>1,'b'=>2,'cnt'=>5];
echo serialize($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
a:3:{s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;s:3:"cnt";i:5;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Language in Php more info on this link [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

This is basically a serailize form of array
of follwoing array

```
      Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [cnt] => 1
            )

    )
```

You can get it back by into array

```
    $a = 'a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:3:"cnt";s:1:"1";}}';
    $unserailize_a = (unserialize($a));
```

To convert an array into string us the   [Serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize)

Comment: **+1** sanjeev , I was about to post the `unserialize` whilst you posted already as I was on a call :P